# Pandas inplace conditional value multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I have tried all solutions I could find on the topic, all of them didn't apply to the dataframe "inplace" and the multiplication never happened.

So here is what I am trying to do:
I have a multilevel column dataframe with many measurements. Every column is ordered like this:

data:

```
                   MeasurementType
                   Value Unit Type
    StudyNumber 
             1     1.0   m/s   a
             2     1.7   m/s   v
             3     10.5  cm/s  b
```

I am trying to convert all measurements with unit m/s to cm/s, i.e. I need to filter all Values with Unit m/s, multiply them by 10 and then change the Unit in the Unit column.

I managed the filter, however when I perform a multiplication on it (by *10, .mul(10) directly, or making a new assignment), it doesn't stick. Printing the dataframe afterwards shows no change in the values.

Here is the code:

```
    unit_df = data.iloc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Unit']


    unit_col_list = []
    for unitcol in unit_df.columns:
        unitget = unit_df[unitcol][unit_df[unitcol].notnull()].unique()
        if unitget.size > 1:
            unit_col_list.append(unitcol)


    unit_col_list =  [item[0] for item in unit_col_list] #so I get the header of the column 
    data_wrongunits = data[unit_col_list]


data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]][data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]]['Unit'] == 'm/s']['Value']*=10
```

or

```
data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]][data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]]['Unit'] == 'm/s']['Value'].mul(10)
```

or

```
data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]][data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]]['Unit'] == 'm/s']['Value']=data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]][data_wrongunits[unit_col_list[0]]['Unit'] == 'm/s']['Value']*10
```

The filter gives me a series of the Value column. Maybe another structure would help?

Comment: does the content of the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) help? Your access of elements looks faulty. Try to use loc, and try to avoid `df[][][]`instead use `df.loc[conditions]`

Comment: I updated my comment, use `loc`for accessing items and don't chain brackets

Comment: Thanks, actually this solved the issue! @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: I assume, that due to the repeated chaining, the warning wasn't raised, though this seems a bit strange. Glad I could help. Note that you can upvote comments and answers and accept answer if they are appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
print (data)
            MeasurementType            MeasurementType1           
                      Value  Unit Type            Value  Unit Type
StudyNumber                                                       
1                       1.0   m/s    a              1.0   m/s    a
2                       1.7   m/s    v              1.7  cm/s    v
3                      10.5  cm/s    b             10.5  mm/s    b

#get columns with Unit
unit_df = data.loc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Unit']
print (unit_df)
            MeasurementType MeasurementType1
                       Unit             Unit
StudyNumber                                 
1                       m/s              m/s
2                       m/s             cm/s
3                      cm/s             mm/s

#create helper df with replace units by constants
#if value not in dict, get NaNs, so replaced by 1
d = {'m/s':10, 'mm/s':100}
df1 = unit_df.applymap(d.get).fillna(1).rename(columns={'Unit':'Value'})
print (df1)
            MeasurementType MeasurementType1
                      Value            Value
StudyNumber                                 
1                      10.0             10.0
2                      10.0              1.0
3                       1.0            100.0
```

---

```
#filter only Value columns and multiple by df1
data[df1.columns] = data[df1.columns].mul(df1)
print (data)
            MeasurementType            MeasurementType1           
                      Value  Unit Type            Value  Unit Type
StudyNumber                                                       
1                      10.0   m/s    a             10.0   m/s    a
2                      17.0   m/s    v              1.7  cm/s    v
3                      10.5  cm/s    b           1050.0  mm/s    b
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
# convert value
df.loc[df.Unit=='m/s', 'Value'] = \
    df.loc[df.Unit=='m/s', 'Value'].mul(100)  #!

# change unit
print df.set_value(df.Unit=='m/s', 'Unit', 'cm/s')
```